# bitcoin daemon use 99.99% io

Tags: bitcoind

bitcoin daemon always use 99.99% IO, without using the Internet <1mbit
this is normal?
bitcoin-0.16.0
bitcoin-0.16.2
iotop:
 99.99 % bitcoind -daemon [bitcoin-schedu

Debian 8 x64

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is normal. bitcoind is downloading the blockchain and writing it to disk. When you are syncing, it has to download and write to disk nearly 200 GB of data, so that is going to use a lot of disk I/O.